# JQuery - Get Cookies from response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have send a POST reuqst to a server, the response has a cookie which i need to store

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url + "api/Login",
        headers: { "Authorization": headerData },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text"
    }).then(
    function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // get the current default Breeze AJAX adapter
        var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");

        var cookies = document.cookie ? document.cookie.split('; ') : [];

        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            console.log(cookies[i]);
        }
        console.log('Cookie');

        ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
            headers: {
                // any headers that you want to specify.
                "Cookie": jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie')
            },
        };
```

but I cannot retireve the cookie, what other tools can I use?

this is the server response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: session-token=227c268d-dae5-4c54-a05a-90f2401592d3; domain=172.18.25.168; path=/
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Dec 2013 20:47:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: is your page on domain `172.18.25.168`?

Comment: yes it is located on this ip

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just echo/print the cookie on your server-side file and then treat it using (data)?

Comment: the server is odata service, i am login using regular jquery post and need to attach the cookie to breeze ajax adapter